# Precaution before getting a whiteboard: carpet stains?

Tags: cleaning, staining, carpet

I'm considering getting a nice large whiteboard for my living room. The problem is: I've got a light-coloured carpet in the room and I'm afraid if the whiteboard marker ink leaves stains on the carpet.
At work, I see the stains on the floor from time to time, but seemingly they come from people cleaning the sponge by rubbing it on the edges, which I wouldn't do of course.

So the question is: In casual use, will I get a color stain below the whiteboard in some time? If yes, is it difficult to clean it from the carpet?

Answer (score 2):

If this is for adults only I wouldn't be worried about it.  I have a large dry-erase board in my office that my family uses and light tan carpet and we have never had an issue.  The key is making sure you whiteboard has a tray to put the markers in and not to leave markers open (which dries them out).

If for kids I would say you run the same risk as them coloring with markers at a table.  Certainly they will destroy things and make a mess.  I specifically left certain things off my house to-do list until my kids got older.

Either way if you want piece of mind I would scotch guard the entire area.  I would use [interior automotive spray](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001NPD7BK) which I use in all my cars and did my kids carpets with them.  A couple of layers and basically you can spill anything within reason on the floor.

Comment: What does the spray actually do? Is it some water-resistant thing like clothes/shoes impregnation? Thanks for the tip certainly. And no, no kids yet (and not even soon I hope!) Once I get kids, I'll move this to their room, I don't worry since it would hardly be the only thing damaging the carpet there :D

Comment: The spray puts a minute coating on the fibers.  It attaches very well to fabric.  The spray deflects polar molecules which are 99% of the stain causing molecules.